# Powershell Scheduled task to only close its own ie session

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

hopefully someone can help me with this? I have a Powershell Scheduled task that opens an IE page to execute part of the task... This can take a bit of time during which another task starts up and runs a short time behind the first... once the first task has finished it closes all the IE windows including the window of the current (behind) running task??? So my question is how do I set it that Task 1 only closes task 1's IE window??

Thanks

Comment: Please share the relevant part of your script

Answer (score 0):

Generic method as you provide almost no detail :
start the process, do stuff, close the process with the relevant ID :

```
$ie=start-process iexplore -passthru
#do stuff with ie
stop-process $ie.id
```